# JavaScript: productos.push is not function

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando crear un carrito de compras para mi aplicacion pero me esta generando varios errores cuando le quiero agregar el localStorage para que guarde la informacion de los productos, solo me genera el error cuando le agrego el localStorage porque ya revise el codigo antes de agregarle esta funcion y si me funciona bien, pero al momento de agregarle la funcion del localStorage me aparecen mas problemas. Me podrian ayudar gracias...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
class Carrito {
//Añadir el producto al carrito
comprarProducto(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.classList.contains("agregar-carrito")){
        const producto = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
        this.leerDatosProducto(producto);
    }
}
leerDatosProducto(producto){
    const infoProducto = {
        imagen : producto.querySelector("img").src,
        titulo : producto.querySelector("h3").textContent,
        precio : producto.querySelector(".precio span").textContent,
        id : producto.querySelector("button").getAttribute("data-id"),
        cantidad : 1
    }
    this.insertarCarrito(infoProducto);
}
insertarCarrito(producto){
    const row = document.createElement("tr");
    row.innerHTML = `
    <td>
        <img src="${producto.imagen}" width=100>
    </td>
    <td>${producto.titulo}</td>
    <td>${producto.precio}</td>
    <td>
        <button href="#" class="borrar-producto fas fa-times-circle" data-id="${producto.id}"></button>
    </td>
`;
listaProductos.appendChild(row);
this.guardarProductoLocalStorage(producto);
}
eliminarProducto(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let producto, productoID;
    if (e.target.classList.contains("borrar-producto")){
        e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        producto = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
        productoID = producto.querySelector("a").getAttribute("data-id");
    }
}
vaciarCarrito(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    while(listaProductos.firstChild){
        listaProductos.removeChild(listaProductos.firstChild);
    }
    return false;
}   
guardarProductoLocalStorage(producto){
   let productos;
   productos = this.obtenerProductosLocalStorage();
   productos.push(producto);
  localStorage.setItem("productos", JSON.stringify(productos));
}
obtenerProductosLocalStorage(){
  let productoLS;
  if(localStorage.getItem("productos") === null){
        productoLS=[];
    }  
    else {
        productoLS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("productos"));
    } 
    return productoLS;
}
```

}

Comment: Hacé un `console.log(productos)` antes de la línea que te está generando problemas para ver cual es su contenido.

Comment: He reproducido como he podido tu escenario y a mi no me da ese error.  Lo que si he visto es que no limpias el localStorage cuando vacias el carrito, y quizas eso te está provocando que tengas datos corruptos de algun modo acumulados de tus pruebas y ya no lo interprete como array. Aquí te dejo un [enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/cu4ot2Lh/) donde lo puedes probar, con el vaciarCarrito corregido (no estoy seguro al 100%, pero mejor que antes seguro)

Comment: Creo que el error esta en let productos; debería ser let productos=[];

Comment: Tal como te comentan, esto: `let productos;` declara una variable llamada `productos` y la establece a `undefined` (comportamiento por defecto para declaraciones con `let` que no se inicializan). Por lo tanto, lo suyo es hacer: `let productos = [];` o siendo aún más estrictos: `const poductos = [];`, ya que el tipo de variable no cambiará durante la ejecución del método, por lo cual declararla con `const` sería lo apropiado. Saludos